# Solving an unmet peer dependency and can't download the proper version.

Tags: node.js, npm

Hey guys I am trying to install google-map-react module from npm and I end up getting this error:

```
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of @types/googlemaps@^3.0.0 
but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-google-maps@9.4.5 requires a peer of 
@types/markerclustererplus@^2.1.29 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
```

Then when I try to use the command:

```
npm install googlemaps@3.0.0
```

I end up getting

```
No matching version found for googlemaps@3.0.0
```

Which to me doesn't make sense because one package asks for it and I get this error. Am I doing something wrong?